# Use CSS in a plugin in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I recently installed the fluid960gs plugin for rails, which includes some stylesheets. How can I use these stylesheets, located in the vendor/plugins/fluid960gs directory? is there a way to do it automatically using the stylesheet_link_tag function, or do i need to manually move them to the public/stylesheets directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can reference them in the vendor directory, but it would be better if you just copy them over to public/stylesheets. This way, if you make any changes to them, you'll have the originals to fall back on, in case you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if you require the plugin in your compass.rb
Then you should be able to import the lib using @import method:

Add the following to your compass.rb config file:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require '960fluid'
```

Then make sure you have imported the grid library into your core .sass or .scss file with:

```
@import "fluid960";
```